# How to create moving cat overlay/foreground for the Zoom meeting?

Tags: zoom-meeting

Today I participated in the Zoom meeting and one participant visibly enjoyed (and of course, other participants as well) the live presence of her cat. Not all of Zoom users can afford to have a cat. Is there possibility to create an overlay/foreground with cat character?

Comment: Step 1: adopt a cat

Comment: You have to have high resolution footage of a cat (difficult with all that hair), ideally with a solid background color, and then [chroma key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key) the background, and then overlay the video on the webcam with something like [ManyCam](https://manycam.com/)

Answer (score 0):

See
[Using Virtual Background in Zoom Room](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/360045819512-Using-Virtual-Background-in-Zoom-Room)
on how to use any suitable image or video as background.

You may also take a picture or video of your office with the cat,
but without yourself, and use this as the background.

You may find many examples by searching the internet.
For example, one image from
[39 Cute Crazy Cat Zoom Teams Backgrounds](https://www.funnymeetingbackgrounds.com/articles/39-cute-crazy-cat-zoom-teams-backgrounds.html) :

[image]

Comment: That's not exactly a *moving* cat. Still cute.

Comment: @Gantendo: Forgot to note that a video can also be used as background. The above image was just for fun.